# Save/Remember ChoiceMode option? (ANDROID)

Tags: android

I'm able to use setChoiceMode to add an checkbox to my ListView items. Is there a solution to remember the items i ticked after closing and re-entering my mobile app? Help!

Comment: Yes. You have to save them somewhere!

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is thing you can use. Tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).